# PHP Punctuation Confusion

Tags: php

I'm having a hard time getting PHP `.` and `"` straight when doing a write to file in a script.  I'm new, so it looks confusing.  The book does it:

```
$outputstring = $date."\t".$tireqty." tires \t".$oilqty." oil \t".$sparkqty." spark plugs\t\$".$totalamount."\t". $address."\n";
```

The question is what's the appropriate placing for the periods and quotations. Due to how it's all mashed together, I don't know what they need to be attached to.  Does each variable need to be `".$VARIABLE."` or are they for the tabs like `\t`".  I want to rearrange it, so there's a segment of string, followed by a variable, then a new line.  What I think it should look like is:

```
$outputstring = $date."\n\ Tires: ".$tireqty."\n\ Oil: ".$oilqty."\n\ Spark Plugs: ".$sparkqty."\n\$".$totalamount."\n".address."\n";
```

Would that even work?  I don't have a php server on the machine I'm at to test.  I hope this makes a little sense, basically I'm not sure what all the punctuation is for.  Thanks.

Comment: typically languages ignore whitespace (except in strings) when parsing.  The whitespace is useful for developers reading the code.  There's nothing wrong with having space between the . and the ""'s to make the code more readable.

Comment: A reason many developer concatenate is because the IDE they use will typically highlight variables this way, making it easier to decipher the code when developing. When you place PHP variables within double-quotes, they get lost in the coloring of the rest of the text.

Comment: @MichaelIrigoyen makes a very good point!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

dot (.) is php's concatenation operator.  In english that means it will glue strings together.

static strings are defined as "quoted" text

in PHP's dynamic typing all scalar (numbers, strings) variables can be used as strings

so...

```
// 3 static strings 
echo "hello" . " " . "world"; // prints 'hello world'

// 2 variables
$a = "hello";
$b = "world";
echo $a . $b ; // prints 'helloworld';  (no space)

// mixed variables and static string
echo $a . " " . $b; // prints 'hello world'
```

additionally you should know there is a difference between single quoted(') and double quoted(") strings

single quotes are taken literally.

```
echo '$a $b'; // prints '$a $b' with literal $
echo "$a $b"; // prints 'hello world' where $a and $b are treated as variables
```

Answer (score 5):

the `.` is the concatenation operator in this scenario. So basically the `.` stitches together two strings, something like this:

```
$string = "Hello";
$newString = $string . " World"; // <-- this var now contains "Hello World"
```

These are all good answers here that should help you understand what's going on, to read more about it you can check out the php manual page:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php

Answer (score 5):

All php variables inside **double quotes(")** gets interpreted:

```
$var  = 'foo';
$var2 = 'bar';

echo "The var content is $var and var2 is $var2";
```

-- The var content is foo and var2 is bar

If you want to concatenate values you need to do it with **dot(.)**:

```
echo 'The var content is'.$var.' and var2 is'.$var2;
```

-- The var content is foo and var2 is bar

Answer (score 4):

The period `.` in php means to concatenate 2 strings together.

Example:

`echo "Hi" . " " . "there";`

Will print:

`Hi there`

The `"` in most languages is the start and end character for a string, however if you want a special character or a `"` in a string it must be escaped by preceding it with a blackslash `\`

Example:

`echo "This \"IS\" the best!";`

Will print:

`This "IS" the best!`

As for how you are doing things, I recommend to put spaces around your periods to help differentiate the pieces you are concatenating together.

Answer (score 4):

for double quotes you can add variables inside but I try to solve your cofusion
in PHP `.` is a seprator & `'` or `"` used for strings

So when you use

```
$name = 'Sam';
$some_variable = 'THIS IS STRING'[seprator]' OTHER_STRING '[seprator]$name;
```

so it will be

```
$some_variable = 'THIS IS STRING'.' OTHER_STRING '.$name;
```

and final value will be

```
$some_variable = 'THIS IS STRING OTHER_STRING Sam';
```

Answer (score 3):

for double quotes you can just add the variable inside--easy!

$outputstring = "$date \t $tireqtytires \t $oilqty oil \t $sparkqty spark plugs \t \$ $totalamount \t $address \n";

Answer (score 2):

The periods are for concatenation.
The quotes are for delineating the literal string boundaries.

What you have there should work. Be careful of the newlines though. In html, they won't output to a new line because they are ignored and you won't need the backslashes after the \n.

Comment: how can I make it output to a new line if the txt file is read with html. Or is there no way around that?

Comment: You can use a <br> tag where you have a \n to let the browser know you expect it output on a new line.

Answer (score 1):

Your example seems fine. Basically, every string needs to be surrounded by quotes. Between each variable/string, there needs to be a `.`

The periods essentially add each individual component (a variable or a string) together to form one long string. Some other languages use `+` instead of `.`, which might be more intuitive